# Explanation of numpy.unique when axis is given

Tags: python, numpy

According to the numpy documentation, `np.unique` would return unique values in an array, also the counts and indices, but when axis is given, I got confused. Can someone explain the example below?

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
>>> a
array([[1 2 3]
       [5 2 3]
       [0 2 3]
       [1 2 3]])
>>> unique_rows, indices, occurrence_count = np.unique(a, axis=0, return_index=True, return_counts=True)
>>> print(unique_rows)   # why not
[[[0 2 3]                  [1 2 3]
  [1 2 3]                  [5 2 3]
  [5 2 3]]]                [0 2 3] but a strange order
>>> print(indices)
[2 0 1]
>>> print(occurrence_count)
[1 2 1]
>>> b, c, d = np.unique(a, axis = 1, return_index = True, return_counts = True)
>>> print(b)
[[1 2 3]
 [5 2 3]
 [0 2 3]
 [1 2 3]]
>>> print(c)  
[0 1 2]       # where do these indices come from?
>>> print(d)
[1 1 1]       # where do these counts come from?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results of [`unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) are sorted lexicographically, like strings. According to the notes section in the docs:

> When an axis is specified the subarrays indexed by the axis are sorted. This is done by making the specified axis the first dimension of the array and then flattening the subarrays in C order. The flattened subarrays are then viewed as a structured type with each element given a label, with the effect that we end up with a 1-D array of structured types that can be treated in the same way as any other 1-D array. The result is that the flattened subarrays are sorted in lexicographic order starting with the first element.

When `axis=0`, you are looking at each row as if it were the element of a structured array. First we compare the first elements to sort. If they are identical, move to the second element, etc. If all the elements are the same, the rows are identical. Clearly `0, 2, 3` comes before `1, 2, 3`. The indices are the locations of the first occurrence of each distinct row in the result. `0, 2, 3` is row 2 in the input, `1, 2, 3` occurs twice at indices 0 and 3: 0 comes first. `5, 2, 3` occurs at index 1.

The same logic applies to `axis=1`, except now you're operating on distinct columns. None of the columns repeat, so all counts are 1. The order should be pretty clear at this point.